# How to avoid releaseing API public key in github for ReactJS application?

Tags: reactjs, git, api, github

I was learning use of API in reactJS, When I made repository in GitHub and pushed my code there, My API_KEY was exposed there and i got mail from GitGuardian that my Secret is exposed,

Here's the code I have changed the key with API_KEY for this question,

```js
export const geoApiOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": API_KEY,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

export const GEO_API_URL = "https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo";
```

I was not aware that my API key would be exposed, So please let me know how should i avoid that in future.

Comment: Your API key should be provided by the environment where you're deploying, and preferably to your server, not your client. If you're hosting static files on GitHub Pages with no server, there is no way to hide your API key, even if you make the repo private, because it'll still be present in the deployed scripts. You will need to run a server somewhere, and set it as an env var or some other sort of supplied secret (depending on the platform you're using).

Comment: I'm not deploying it on GitHub pages, i am learning reactjs, so i made repo on GitHub and pushed what i have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using secret keys like API_KEY or DATABASE_URL and pushing source code to GitHub you should create a `.env` file in the root of your project. Then in your .env file, you can write your `API_URL` and use env variables in your source code. Then you should create a `.gitignore` file that ensures which files will be ignored when you publish your code to GitHub.

Comment: Can you send one example of .env file?

Comment: Simply crete a .env file at the root of the project and write your variables and give them a name. Eg: ```FIREBASE_URL=http://YOUR_FIREBASE_URL/example.json``` This article is showing how to add env variables at node: https://www.codementor.io/@parthibakumarmurugesan/what-is-env-how-to-set-up-and-run-a-env-file-in-node-1pnyxw9yxj

Comment: Use of .env.local helped me, and there's rule that variable should start with REACT_APP_ (eg. REACT_APP_GEODB_API_KEY), and call that variable in your .js file as process.env.<variable name> (eg. process.env.REACT_APP_GEODB_API_KEY).

Comment: REACT_APP is react specific prefix and you don't need .env.local because it only works for all environments except test. Checkout :https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used. You can use the .env file too. Furthermore, I am happy that you resolved your error and I would be happy if you upvote or choose the correct answer Besides this things can easily find with a little googling. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply using GitHub to document your code, you can store your API key in a separate file.

###### api-key.json

```
{
  "apiKey": "abcd1234"
}
```

###### app.js

```
import { apiKey } from "api-key.json";

export const geoApiOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": apiKey,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

export const GEO_API_URL = "https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo";
```

And simply tell Git to ignore the file when publishing your code

###### .gitignore

```
# ...
api-key.json
```

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at all the answer I got and searched internet,

The below code worked for me.

created .env file in my root directory,

**.env**

```js
REACT_APP_GEODB_API_KEY= MY_API_KEY
```

- replacing actual key with MY_API_KEY,

then need to run this command

> npm install dotenv --save

use the variable in code like this

**api.js**

```js
export const geoApiOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_GEODB_API_KEY,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

export const GEO_API_URL = "https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo";
```

add the **.env** file to **.gitignore**

Done.

Now restart your App using,

> npm start run